# Can i use scenes in VSE to group video tracks?

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I am doing my first steps in Blender's VSE and i am trying to familiarise myself with the workflow.

I am trying to edit several video clips to produce a single output video and i would like to somehow group some of these clips together to apply common color correction, time manipulation etc and to unclutter the main timeline. For this i created a new scene (let's say scene2) by either Copy Settings or Full Copy, moved some of the clips from my main scene (let's say scene1) to it and then on the main scene i did Add > Scene... > Scene2. When i try to playback on the main timeline though, on the part of the Scene2 i either get a blank screen or a square 3D object.

What am i doing wrong? Is there a better way to achieve the same result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add scene2, blender does not import the Video sequence but the 3D animation, hence the cube. You could export scene 2 in a movieclip and then import it in scene 1

You could group the clips (in scene1) by selecting the strips and then <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>. ( <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> to ungroup)

Comment: How do you export the scene to a movieclip, by rendering to a new video? Isn't it too much of a hassle to do this every time? What if you would like to change something in a later phase, like the position or the color settings, you have to do it all over again?

Comment: MetaStrips look more promising though. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

An other option:
You could also download the blender gooseberry branch. https://builder.blender.org/download/

There you can make different scenes using the video sequence editor. Then you can work the way you discribed above. You can import the one scene into the other. Then if you click on the scene you imported in the sequence editor, you will see a cube, but in the properties panel under the tab scene you can check use sequence. and then you will see the movie files.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for letting me know this, i will download the gooseberry branch to try it. Is it stable for everyday use? Also, is there some summary of all the changes that are part of the branch so far?

Comment: @charis, you don't need the Gooseberry Branch any more - it's now supported in [2.77](https://developer.blender.org/rB485ea43).