# Video Sequence Editor clips

Tags: video-sequence-editor, video

I am wondering if Blenders Video Sequence Editor has the concept of clips, that I can temporarily store.

For example:

- First I would take a video clip from file explorer and drag into the edit strip view.
- Then I would take the strip and make a bunch of hard cuts that would result in a bunch of new smaller clips. Could I then take those smaller cut clips from the edit strip and store them somewhere in the project without having to export or anything. So I could take any particular clip and decide I want that here or here...

Hope my explanation made sense.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunatelly I never figured out such a function..

this is my solution to the problem:

1. group all your imported videos into a metastrip on layer 1 with <kbd>CTRL + G</kbd> and access them selecting the strip and tapping <kbd>TAB</kbd>

[image: 01]

2. have your cuts into the metastrip

[image: 02]

3. copy your desired clips from the metastrip <kbd>CTRL + C</kbd> exit the metalevel unselecting everything and tapping <kbd>TAB</kbd> so paste wherever you want with <kbd>CTRL + V</kbd>. I suggest you to keep the 1st layer hidden, so the "metatemp" *(i will call It this way)* will stay metatemp and not visible on the preview area.

[image: 03]

4. repeat these operations from step 2 any time you need.

Comment: So I guess video editing with Blender is not quite up to snuff of dedicated video editing software like final cut or lightworks...

Comment: the VSE of blender is a new feature, will surely be implemented in the future.. For now, It's not the best video editor on the world... but for me, It works enough, love the proxies function :)

Answer (score 0):

You could also download the blender gooseberry branch. https://builder.blender.org/download/

You can make different scenes using the video sequence editor. So like in final cut pro you can make different timelines. 
In blender (the gooseberry branch) you can then add the scenes (but you have to check use sequence in the properties panel (N)) in the timeline you want to work in.

[for more info](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35477/can-i-use-scenes-in-vse-to-group-video-tracks/35482#35482)

Comment: You don't need the Gooseberry Branch any more - it's now supported in [2.77](https://developer.blender.org/rB485ea43).